# Read resource file in eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to simply read a file from the file system in eclipse.  In main.java I want to be able to get the path and read the resource.txt file.

```
Java Resources
    - src/main/java
          -mainFolder
              - main.java
    - src/test/resources
          -resourceFolder
              - resource.txt
```

My attempt:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
classLoader.getResource("resourceFolder/resource.txt").getFile();
```

Error being displayed is NullPointerException.

Comment: If there was an error message/stack trace, share it, please. I assume file couldn't be found, but contained info could help fix quicker.

Comment: Use below syntax,File file = new File("src/sample.txt");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is produced because `getResource` returns `null` as it's unable to find the file in the provided path.

You seem to be missing to include the `test/resources` folder in your path.

Try this:

```
classLoader.getResource("test/resources/resourceFolder/resource.txt").getFile();
```